# Android 2.3: GridView out of order after scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I have a GridView loaded with a bunch of custom views.  When I scroll up or down, the views that went off screen before are now replaced with different views.  Any ideas why this happens?

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.collection_item, parent, false);

    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes    
        ImageView movieImage = (ImageView)rLayout.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
        TextView movieTitle = (TextView)rLayout.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
        TextView movieDescription = (TextView)rLayout.findViewById(R.id.movieDescription);

        movieImage.setImageResource(movies[position]);
        movieTitle.setText(movieNames[position]);
        movieDescription.setText(movieDescriptions[position]);
    } else {
        rLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
    }
    return rLayout;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind I figured it out.  Just put all the initialization code into the (convertView == null) part and the setter methods after the if/else block.